# Apoptosis related

Tags: apoptosis

I have two questions 
1. Is it possible for a cell undergoing apoptosis to induce apoptosis in 
     a surrounding cell?
2. If we induce apoptosis in a normal cell surrounding a tumor. 
     Is it possible for the molecules released during apoptosis to
     differentiate between normal and cancerous cells?